# Conda dependency from custom channel is not getting installed

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm struggling with building my own conda package. The build runs OK and the meta.yaml file looks like this:

```yaml
package:
  name: simple_nodes_embedding
  version: "0.1.0"

source:
  path: ..

build:
  number: 0

requirements:
  build:
    - pip
    - python=3.7
    - setuptools
  run:
    - python=3.7
    - pypardiso
    - networkx >=2.4
    - scipy
    - numpy>=1.18.1
    - markdown
    - statsmodels


about:
  home: https://github.com/monomonedula/simple-graph-embedding
  license: Apache License 2.0
  license_file: LICENSE.txt
  summary: Simple deterministic algorithm for generating graph nodes topological embeddings.
```

However, when I run

```
conda install simple_nodes_embedding -c local -c defaults -c conda-forge -c haasad
```

and the built package is installed, pypardiso package from haasad channel is not getting installed.

```py
>>> from simple_nodes_embedding import embedding
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/vhhl/dev/simple-graph-embedding/simple_nodes_embedding/embedding.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pypardiso import spsolve
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pypardiso'
```

How do I fix this? And what is the correct way to specify depenedencies from custom channels when creating conda packages?

Comment: Please also include the full error message!

Comment: @cel done. however nothing special about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the reason it wasn't working was that i specified the wrong name (I copied a part of it from the pypardiso package and forgot to replace the name) for the package in my `setup.py` file. I changed it and now it works fine